# What is the minimum value of n, such that n! is completely divisible by $13^{28}$ ? (n! denotes the factorial of number n)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have 2 solutions given in my text book in which I have doubts

Solution 1:-

Since $169!$ has $13^{14}$ in its prime factorization

hence for $13^{28}$ the number will be (169*2)! = 338!

My doubt in this solution is :- what is the purpose of multiplying 169 with 2 , and is it by fluke the correct answer is coming ? or is there any logic behind it ? shouldn't we also check whether 337! could also be our number, why did the solution in the textbook not check for it ?

Solution 2:-

28*13= 364

364! has $13^{30}$ in its prime factorization

(364-13)! = 351! will have $13^{29}$ in its prime factorization

(351-13)! = 338! will have $13^{28}$ in its prime factorization

my doubt in this solution is as to why we did 13*28 in the first step and why are we reducing 13 each time from the previous number ?

Comment: Is "completely divisible" any different from everyday ordinary divisible?

Comment: no ,it is the usual meaning of remainder to be 0 upon division @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 1):

First question--why start with $13\cdot28=364$? If you write down all the positive integers from $1$ to $364$, you will find that $28$ of them are divisible by $13$,  viz $(1\cdot 13,2\cdot 13,3\cdot 13,\dots 28\cdot 13)$. So $364!$ will have at least $28$ factors of $13$ and be divisible by $13^{28}$. However, a check reveals that there are actually $30$ factors of $13$ contained within the numbers in this list.

Second question--why decrement by $13$ in steps? Each time you decrement by $13$,  you remove one number from the original list that was divisible by $13$. When you do this twice, you get to a number ($338$) that when it is the largest number of a similar list, results in a list that has only $28$ factors of $13$ among its members.

The reason the original list contains more than enough factors of $13$ is because two of its members ($13\cdot 13$ and $26\cdot 13$) each have two factors of $13$, allowing for the removal from the list of two larger numbers divisible by $13$